# need to add custom field in more products

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field

Hi i'm gonna be completely honest idk shiz for code i just need this to work on my site, there's a category of products that i want to have this custom field how can i code it to do that?, this is the current code i'm using (mixed a bunch of code together to get this)

```
// Display additional product fields (+ jQuery code)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_additional_product_fields', 9 );
function display_additional_product_fields(){
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();
    if (($id == 1963 ) || ($id == 2074 ))   :
?>
<p class="form-row validate-required" id="image" >
    <label for="file_field"><?php echo __("Upload Image") . ': '; ?>
        <input type='file' name='image' accept='image/*'>
    </label>
</p>
<?php
    endif;
}
```

there is more but this is what matters currently i can only get two products to have the field with the if statement or all of them i need it to work for 7 specific ones how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow you to display the upload form when the product is in the `$special_category` product category.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_additional_product_fields', 9 );
function display_additional_product_fields() {
    global $product;

    // Product category or slug that will allow the upload field to be displayed.
    $special_category = 314;

    if ( ! has_term( $special_category, 'product_cat', $product->ID ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
<p class="form-row validate-required" id="image" >
    <label for="file_field"><?php esc_html_e( 'Upload Image:', 'text-domain' ); ?>
        <input type='file' name='image' accept='image/*'>
    </label>
</p>
<?php
}
```